# how can i use activity to change background in another activity by clicking a button

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm beginner in android and this is my first post.

In my application i have 2 activities , one of them is background_Setting and it's .xml is background_main .
in its .xml have buttons when i clicked anyone it change the background for this activity but i want to change the whole app with all activities not in background_main only

how can i make it ? Thanks in advance

```
package com.example.back;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class backgroundSetting extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener    
{    
ImageButton BlackeButton;    
ImageButton WhiteButton;    
ImageButton BlueeButton;    
ImageButton GreenButton;       
RelativeLayout myLO;    

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.backgrounds);

        BackGroundBlac();

        BlackeButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        WhiteButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        BlueeButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        GreenButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

private void BackGroundBlac() 
{
    myLO=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.backgroundActivity);
    BlackeButton=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.black);
    WhiteButton=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.white);
    BlueeButton=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.blue);
    GreenButton=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.green);  
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) 
{
    switch (v.getId()) 
    {
    case R.id.black:

        myLO.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

        break;

    case R.id.white:

        myLO.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

        break;

    case R.id.blue:

        myLO.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

        break;

    case R.id.green:

        myLO.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

        break;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You could create a BroadcastReceiver in `onCreate`:

```
BroadcastReceiver mColorChangedReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        int color = intent.getIntExtra("color", -1);
        myLO.setBackgroundColor(color);
    }
};
```

And register/unregister it in the lifecycle methods:

```
@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();

    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity())
        .registerReceiver(mColorChangedReceiver, new IntentFilter("com.example.app.COLOR_CHANGED"));
}

@Override
public void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();

    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).unregisterReceiver(mColorChangedReceiver);
}
```

And when user clicks to change the color send the broadcast:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.app.COLOR_CHANGED");
intent.putExtra("color", Color.BLACK);
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
```